# How to animate image using HorizantalPager?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have three backgrounds in Box and that box contains HorizontalPager and a Image Component which changes according to HorizontalPager Current page but there is no animation how to added animation like this
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1588664/screenshots/8257559/media/d94b36cb7822008df8055c90ca6e2238.mp4

And here is my code preview
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i2ix1Xdx-TK2SVPgx8MhFZWfqQnhZcr5/view?usp=sharing

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 3)
val currentIndex = pagerState.currentPage
val currentPageOffset = pagerState.currentPageOffset
val poster = listOf(
    R.drawable.red,R.drawable.blue,R.drawable.green
)
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(poster[currentIndex]),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) { page ->
        val maxOffset = 70.dp
        val offset = maxOffset * when (page) {
            currentIndex -> {
                currentPageOffset.absoluteValue
            }
            currentIndex - 1 -> {
                1 + currentPageOffset.coerceAtMost(0f)
            }
            currentIndex + 1 -> {
                1 - currentPageOffset.coerceAtLeast(0f)
            }
            else -> {
                1f
            }
        }
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.7f)
                .padding(22.dp)
                .offset(y = offset),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
            elevation = 110.dp
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Why don't you try calculate offset same as I did with `currentIndex` `currentPageOffset`? Add prints to see what values these two take during scrolling, then calculate offset of your image respectfully

Comment: I have tried It's animates very differently and I can't figure it out how to do this Here we need to animate both images the image which is selected and the images where the user is dragging means -1.0 or 1.0. I am able to animate one image but not the other image.

Comment: Philip please please

Comment: I'm not answering because it's not that simple, and I don't have so much time right now. Offset wouldn't work, you probably need to use a custom shape to hide part of the image, and this shape should have parameters on which part you need to hide right now.

Comment: Okay I'll try but if you get time then please help me

Comment: I have added the background image in a Horizontal Pager then I tried to animate it using offset but it is behaving wired

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I have done with the animation. Want to see?

Comment: https://github.com/abhishekumar-dev/Compose/

Comment: That looks cool! Congratulations on solving this problem yourself!

Comment: I should thank you for this Thank you soo much 